# where is the C# documentation on Amazon S3?

Tags: c#, amazon-s3

I'm creating an application that uses amazon s3 for storage in C#. It may be seen to be a stupid question. Where is the documentation on C# aws library?

I'm really like some documentation on the functions calls I've been using.

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is the [AWS SDK for .NET](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/) site, at the bottom of which you will find the [Reference Documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/Index.html).  Note that the reference documentation also gets installed to your local Visual Studio Help.